# Axios change http to https

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, axios

I have server that accept only http (no https). And when I call an api, axios automatically change http to https.

I create axios instance here:

```
export const axiosAgent = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/v1/",
});
```

But in browser http changes to https, so it become: `https://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/v1/all`

and I get `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

How can I prevent that?

**UPDATE**
Request Header:

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Referer: http://localhost:3000/patients
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36
```

and there is no response header.

and now I get `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Comment: No doubt the server is redirecting your requests.  The browser isn't going to do this on its own for XHR or Fetch.

Comment: @Brad But it woks in postman, or when I open that url in new tab.(With Allowing `Insecure content` )

Comment: Can you open your browser's developer tools and show the full request/response headers for one of your API calls?  Also, you shouldn't be getting `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` just because of a protocol difference.

Comment: @Brad I update question

Comment: What's the full request URI?  And, which error are you getting?  Name not resolved, or an SSL protocol error?  Sounds to me like you're using HTTPS with a port that's HTTP.

Comment: Full url is: `https://xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/api/v1/operator/patient`, But as I said, I create axios with `http` and in browser it changed to `htttps`. I don't know really what is happening.Sometimes `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` and sometimes `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`, but main point is to disable redirect to `https`.

Comment: I don't know how to help you if you can't post the request and response.  Whatever `xxx.xxx.xxx` is is probably relevant because of your DNS error.  But, what you posted clearly shows `localhost`... and if that name isn't resolved, then there are other issues.  Besides, you show us the protocol error... so if you can't show us the request that lead to your original problem, I don't know how to help you.  If something is redirecting, it must be server-side.  If you believe otherwise, show the request/response, with the method and path, and the status line in response.

Comment: The `xxx.xxx.xxx` is server port. Just some numbers.

Comment: I request from `localhost` to my server which is `xxx.xxx.xxx:8080`

Comment: I think problem is about browser that blocks `http` call. Because as I said when I open that url in new tab(Without using axios) firstly doen't work and when I allow `Insecure content` in site settings it works.

Comment: `localhost` should resolve to `127.0.0.1` or `::1`... anything else is non-standard.  Anyway, good luck figuring it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just remove `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">`
from head in html. and problem solved.
This meta tag change all http request to https one, so this is not related to axios.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the extension "HTTPS Everywhere" and that caused the redirection. Please check if you have any such extensions installed.

If Yes, disable the extension for time being.

Answer (score -2):

You can set url param with protocol.
Example:

```
axios({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:5050'
});
```

Comment: Here I just create an instance of axois. When I call api, I use axiosAgent.get(...)

Comment: Maybe you are trying to send request from https to http, and browser change protocal automatically ?

Comment: Yes, When Change `Insecure content` to `Allow` when I open it in new tab and It works but I my app not work.